Is there any significance to the identity $\zeta(6)\zeta(2)^2 = \zeta(8)\zeta(2) + \zeta(6)\zeta(4)?$
I found this identity involving the first few special values of the Riemann Zeta function
$$\zeta(6)\zeta(2)^2 = \zeta(8)\zeta(2) + \zeta(6)\zeta(4).$$
I assume that there are many similar identities (though it seems this is the simplest one of this type).
This is an open-ended question:
Are there any interesting interpretations to such identities? Is there any reason at all to believe that this is not a simple coincidence?
Edit: $$\zeta(6)\zeta(10) + \zeta(2)\zeta(4)\zeta(10) = \zeta(6)^2\zeta(2)^2.$$
This one too, can be represented as a pair of fractions summing to $1$ (see comments). In this case, the fractions are $\frac{4}{11}$ and $\frac{7}{11}$.

There are no doubt lots of them, but maybe harder to get simple ones where the coefficients are all $1.$ $\zeta(2n)$ is always a rational multiple of $\pi^{2n},$ so you can get a lot of these. $2\zeta(2)^2=5\zeta(4),$ for example. This is really a question, when restricted to even integers, about Bernoulli numbers. The real question is, can you find examples which are not for even integers only.

@ThomasAndrews $\zeta(-1)=\zeta(-13)$ has coefficients of $1$ and does not use even integers.

I guess one cool thing this says is that $$\prod_{p} \frac{p^{10}}{(p^6-1)(p^2 - 1)^2} = \prod_{p} \frac{p^{10}}{(p^8-1)(p^2-1)} + \prod_{p} \frac{p^{10}}{(p^6-1)(p^4-1)}$$

Yeah, I should have specified positive odd integers, the ones for which we have no closed formulas. @Henry

I suppose you can also rearrange to get $\frac{\zeta(8)}{\zeta(2)\zeta(6)} + \frac{\zeta(4)}{\zeta(2)^2} = 1$.

Which in fact says $\frac{3}{5} + \frac{2}{5} = 1$.

Or, after simplifying in terms of Euler products, $$\prod_{p} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^2 + 1} - \frac{1}{p^4+1} \right) + \prod_{p} \left( 1 - \frac{2}{p^2+1} \right) = 1.$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function says, $$\zeta(2n)={1\over n+(1/2)}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\zeta(2k)\zeta(2n-2k)$$
